# UIAlertController Segue to Different Page (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, uialertcontroller

I was able to write a UIAlertController for my button, and it work fine, but I don't know how to segue to a different page once I press the YES or OK button. At the moment, the YES or OK button goes nowhere.

```
@IBAction func SubmitButton(sender: AnyObject) {


        if a > 28.87 {


            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "H4 with Guide Pins", message: "Can it be removed?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } 

        else if data2.text == "" {


            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Dimension", message: "Missing Data Input.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        else {


            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "H4 with Guide Pins", message: "Enter Swallow Dimension.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            self.view.endEditing(true)

        }

    }
```

Comment: what about implementing handler instead nil

Comment: Hmmmm...I never used handler before.  How would I write that code?

Comment: http://swiftoverload.com/uialertcontroller-swift-example/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could create a segue in your storyboard, control dragging from the yellow view controller at the top of a scene to a new view controller. Then give that segue an identifier in the inspector. You can call that from the handler in your code.

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .Default, handler:  { action in self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueIdentifier", sender: self) }
```

Comment: I got it to segue, but how do change the ui image when you segue to the other ViewController?

Comment: You could call prepareForSegue and use segue.destinationViewController to set an image property in your next View Controller.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in Swift 3

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email Verification Required", message: "You will receive an email shortly to verify your account this must be done before you can sign in", preferredStyle: .alert)
let backToSignIn = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToSignIn", sender: self)})
alertController.addAction(backToSignIn)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Where `backToSignIn` is the segue name.